# Is Cystone effective against UTI?

Tags: dogs, health, medicines, urinary-tract-disease

Is Cystone effective against UTI (urinary tract infection)?

**Background:**

The vet prescribed Cystone and Tavanic for my dog's UTI. I personally had issues with medicines labeled as herbal—like Cystone—in the past. What stood out is that it had no pamphlet with side effects, etc.

I couldn't find it on drugs.com either, only found it on [Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/HIMALAYA-Infection-Treatment-Prevention-Gluten-free/dp/B003EB3Q4E).

I'm seeing the vet again soon and would like to know more before the visit.

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3925635/ seems to be a paper on it., saying there's no real effect from it.

Comment: I am wondering if it's based on cranberries, as these are known to help with UTI's.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - I've been to the vet, mentioned my concerns and that I only gave it twice then stopped it. And mentioned the paper you linked. The vet didn't fight back at all and said it's okay [to stop using it]. And to continue with the Tavanic. Feel free to post it as an answer with a quotation (so it doesn't become a link-only answer) and I'll accept. Thank you for the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a herbal 'supposedly' ayurvedic medicine made by a pretty big supplement manufacturer who also has a sideline in veterinary products.

Apparently there were *[human](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3925635/)* trials and they were inconclusive

> This short term study does not suggest that Cystone® affects those
> urinary chemistries commonly measured and known to influence calcium
> oxalate stone formation, nor does decrease renal calcium stone burden
> over a 1 year period. It is possible elements of the urine were
> affected that are not typically measured (e.g., glycoprotein
> inhibitors). A longer term study with more patients would be necessary
> to detect changes in stone events or enhanced stone passage, or
> effects on other stone types. In any new study of Cystone, the
> botanical authenticity of each individual herb will need to be
> documented by the manufacturer using high pressure liquid
> chromatography. This short term trial failed to find evidence that
> Cystone® prevents kidney stone formation and growth in recurrent
> calcium oxalate stone formers.

<sub>Erickson SB, Vrtiska TJ, Lieske JC. Effect of Cystone® on Urinary Composition and Stone Formation Over a One Year Period. Phytomedicine : international journal of phytotherapy and phytopharmacology. 2011;18(10):863-867. doi:10.1016/j.phymed.2011.01.018.</sub>

I also found a list of the herbs it contains on [Himalaya's website](http://www.himalayawellness.com/products/pharmaceuticals/cystone-tablet-syrup.htm)

Didymocarpus pedicellata
[Bergenia ligulata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bergenia_ligulata)
[Tribulus terrestris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tribulus_terrestris)

Oddly *some* of these might have an effect on their own in studies -
[this came up searching for](http://ttps://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17140554) Didymocarpus but this is in a test tube apparently.

I'd say it's inconclusive - and it feels a little like something that's given as a 'complimentary' medicine rather than something that's proven to work.